# Using FullSimplify to simplify an expression with assumptions

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I am working with Poisson brackets of Angular momentum, and I want Mathematica to be able to return the angular momentum function if the Poisson bracket yields that result. I.e. provided

```
PoissonBracket[a_ , b_] := 
  Module[{position, momentum}, 
    position = {x, y, z};
    momentum = {px, py, pz};
    result = 
      D[a, {position}].D[b, {momentum}] - D[a, {momentum}].D[b, {position}]]

FLx[x_, y_, z_, px_, py_, pz_] := y*pz - z*py;
Lx = FLx[x, y, z, px, py, pz];
FLy[x_, y_, z_, px_, py_, pz_] := z*px - x*pz;
Ly = FLy[x, y, z, px, py, pz];
FLz[x_, y_, z_, px_, py_, pz_] := x*py - y*px;
Lz = FLz[x, y, z, px, py, pz];
```

(I did this to be able to compute actual values later on and to take Jacobians in an easier way)

If I compute

```
PoissonBracket[Lx, Ly]
```

I get `pz y - py z`, but I want to get `Lz` straight away instead. I have tried using simplify with assumptions in various ways, but

```
FullSimplify[PoissonBracket[Ly, Lz], Lx]
```

returns `True`

```
 FullSimplify[PoissonBracket[Ly, Lz], Lx == pz y - py z]
```

returns `pz y - py z`, so it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

PoissonBracket[a_, b_] := Module[{position, momentum}, position = {x, y, z};
  momentum = {px, py, pz};
  result = 
   D[a, {position}].D[b, {momentum}] - D[a, {momentum}].D[b, {position}]]

FLx[x_, y_, z_, px_, py_, pz_] := y*pz - z*py;
FLy[x_, y_, z_, px_, py_, pz_] := z*px - x*pz;
FLz[x_, y_, z_, px_, py_, pz_] := x*py - y*px;
```

If you [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`) the values of `Lx`, `Ly`, and `Lz` then these can never appear in a result since they will always be evaluated to their `Set` values. Perhaps you want replacement rules.

```
rules = {FLx[x, y, z, px, py, pz] -> Lx,
  FLy[x, y, z, px, py, pz] -> Ly,
  FLz[x, y, z, px, py, pz] -> Lz}

(* {pz y - py z -> Lx, -pz x + px z -> -pz x + px z, py x - px y -> Lz} *)

PoissonBracket[FLx[x, y, z, px, py, pz], FLy[x, y, z, px, py, pz]] /. rules

{* Lz *)
```

Comment: Thank you loads! Is there any way to avoid writing the FLx[x, y, z, px, py, pz], i.e. just FLx to take derivatives or any more compact notation?

Comment: `flx = FLx[x, y, z, px, py, pz];` Then use `flx`